# How can I implement a tutorial for my app?

Tags: android, layout, transparent

I want to create a transparent layer in full screen.

I also want to turn that particular view (Example text view, or image view) into white and also add arrows.

I understand the text font changes.

[image]

Comment: create Framelayout and make it height and width match parent an alpha=0.6. now add your desire infos inside framelayout , when use click set its visibility gone

Comment: thanks for the idea bt how will i turn the views into white and that to the arrows point in such a direction irrespective of whichever device my app is running...please upvote the question..

Comment: same as your default layout created. just create same in frame layout with some alpha\

Comment: you need to create some overlay layout with some alpha on your main layout and find the position of your view and put it in overlay view at same position